# Connecting snowflake database in Dbeaver, while Snowflake is behind Okta. Seeing error authenticator not accepted by your Snowflake account config

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, single-sign-on, okta, dbeaver

I'm seeing this error in dbeaver when trying to connect to a Snowflake database:

> The specified authenticator is not accepted by your Snowflake account
> configuration.  Please contact your local system administrator to get
> the correct URL to use.

Previously we've connected to this snowflake db in dbeaver but I've been unsuccessful since we added Snowflake to OKTA. Here are the steps I've taken so far:

In Connection settings, added `Authenticator: externalbrowser`

In the Driver properties under User Properties added the new key/value: `authenticator : https://ouroktaurl.com` (I used the same URL we have in snowflake's security integration SAML2_SSO_URL, I believe that's correct?)

Updated the snowflake-JDBC driver to 3.13.29.jar

Comment: If you are using Native Okta SSO then set the `authenticator=https://<okta_account_name>.okta.com` in the connection string. That should be all what is needed.

Comment: @Sergiu Unfortunately I tried that already, its the 3rd step I did

Comment: If you just set `Authenticator: externalbrowser` in the Connection setttings without anything else, does a browser opens up when you try to Connect?

Comment: @Sergiu - no, a browser doesn't open when I set Authenticator: externalbrowser and run a "Test Connection", I've also tried without setting the Authenticator and I still see the same error as in my post

Comment: This might be related to some apps/software on your machine. When I set on my side the `authenticator: externalbrowser` in DBeaver, a browser windows open when I click on Connect.